# How to make the CENTOS linux to run php

Tags: php, centos

**I am using CentOS linux**

i have installed:

**CENTOS**

**APACHE**

**PHP**

The Problem is when i run php file only the code of the file shows not it's self as 
my phpinfo works fine

where i have mistaken

thanks

Comment: are you trying to run this php file from the command line?  have you tried `php -i`?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the output you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check php start and end tags. 
If you are using short tags,  then you have to configure it in php.ini.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php